# Override Spock mock with method instead of value

Tags: groovy, spock

I know that using Spock I can create a Mock and set a return value on a method e.g.

```
    idpClient.adminCreateUser(_) >> [
            user: new UserType()
    ]
```

How can I set a method on the Mock so I can customise the value that gets returned? I want to do something like:

```
    idpClient.metaClass.adminCreateUser = { AdminCreateUserRequest adminCreateUserRequest ->
        UserType user = new UserType()
        user.setUsername(adminCreateUserRequest.getUsername())
        AdminCreateUserResult result = new AdminCreateUserResult()
        result.setUser(user)
        return result
    }
```

Though obviously the above does not work (it returns null). I've looked at the documentation but all I've found is how to return a fixed value (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you ought to read the Spock manual. There is a section on [computing return values](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_computing_return_values). There is no need to use meta classes, the Spock DSL provides syntactical means for stubbing.

I made up this little example for you as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q64961803;

class UserType {
  private String userName;
  public void setUserName(String userName) { this.userName = userName; }
  public String getUserName() { return userName; }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q64961803;

public class AdminCreateUserResult {
  private UserType user;
  public void setUser(UserType user) { this.user = user; }
  public UserType getUser() { return user; }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q64961803;

public class AdminCreateUserRequest {
  private String userName;
  public AdminCreateUserRequest(String userName) { this.userName = userName; }
  public String getUserName() { return userName; }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q64961803;

public class IDPClient {
  public AdminCreateUserResult adminCreateUser(AdminCreateUserRequest adminCreateUserRequest) {
    AdminCreateUserResult userResult = new AdminCreateUserResult();
    UserType userType = new UserType();
    userType.setUserName("real user");
    userResult.setUser(userType);
    return userResult;
  }
}
```

Shen the corresponding Spock specification would look like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q64961803

import spock.lang.Specification

class IDPClientTest extends Specification {
  def test() {
    given: "mock IDPClient with stubbed method"
    IDPClient idpClient = Mock() {
      adminCreateUser(_) >> { AdminCreateUserRequest adminCreateUserRequest ->
        UserType user = new UserType()
        user.setUserName(adminCreateUserRequest.getUserName())
        AdminCreateUserResult result = new AdminCreateUserResult()
        result.setUser(user)
        result
      }
    }
    def request = new AdminCreateUserRequest("test user")

    expect: "real IDPClient behaves normally"
    new IDPClient().adminCreateUser(request).user.userName == "real user"

    and: "mock IDPClient displays stub behaviour"
    idpClient.adminCreateUser(request).user.userName == "test user"
  }
}
```

Comment: I did read the manual and I tried that - still returns null.

Comment: Did you really try my example? Maybe yours is different, otherwise it would work. I need to see an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but at least the class under test. I cannot debug what I cannot reproduce. Just posting a small test snippet and saying that it does not work is not a good way to ask a question. Make my effort worthwhile and please do your homework. The MCVE would have been your job in the first place, not mine. I mean no offence, just want to be very clear about what is required for me to help you.

Comment: You do not show how you instantiate the mock and I cannot verify if the stubbed method might be final (which means stubbing would have no effect) as well as other things I want to check.

Comment: Feedback, please. Thank you.

Comment: I can't remember now - I moved on from the issue and I must have solved it some other way.

Comment: Um, well, you are not making it particularly worthwhile to answer your questions like this. I invested time, effort and even produced a complete MCVE which provably works. If your are too busy to follow up on answers to your own questions here, better do not ask in the first place. Would you please at least upvote and accept my correct answer instead of just bluntly stating that you cannot remember and moved on? I do not find that so nice, to be honest. We can subsequently both delete our latest comments regarding this issue.